# Nodejs Nginx 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have set up my server on Digital Ocean and running it on `port: 3000` using `pm2`. when I curl to my server in the do it responds correctly.

```
curl http://localhost:3000/
```

This is my nginx configuration.

```
server {
        listen 80;

        #root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        #index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name api.skreem.co;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/api.skreem.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.skreem.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
}
```

I am getting logs on my Nginx access and error logs as follows

```
#access_log
106.51.111.247 - - [20/Mar/2020:09:27:34 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 584 "http://api.skreem.co/api/v2/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/
537.36"

#error_log
2020/03/20 09:27:34 [error] 1651#1651: *121 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 106.51.111.247, server: api.skreem.co, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "ht
tp://127.0.0.1:3000/favicon.ico", host: "api.skreem.co", referrer: "http://api.skreem.co/api/v2/"
```

On my Pm2 monitor I am not getting any Logs. I have rechecked the `proxy_pass` but still not able to get nginx to pass it on to the nodejs server.

Am getting

> 502 Bad Gateway error

Comment: check your firewall settings

Comment: Check if  network path from nginx server (which i don't where is sitting- might be on different VM)  to your nodejs server is working ?  First Ping & then check firewall setting as @AdeelNawaz suggested.